# Jinja2 Environment ImportError in Django 1.10 with Python 3.5

Tags: python, django

I have a Django 1.10 project (with Python 3.5, and Jinja2 2.8 for templates) setup like this:

[image: Directory structure]

*Consider the red marks as `mysite`

File `jinja2.py` defines this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import reverse

from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

And this file is called in `settings.py` like this:

```
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'environment': 'mysite.jinja2.environment',
    },
},
```

But when I run the server and visit a URL with view that calls a Jinja2 template, I get the following error:

[image: ImportError]

I spent several hours searching the Internet to find a solution, but unable to resolve this.

The entire setup was done following the official Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2

Thanks for your response(s)

Comment: What version of jinja are you using? Also try to remove `from __future__ import absolute_import` line, since it only for Python 2 only.

Comment: It's Jinja2 2.8. I have now edited and mentioned this in the original post. Thanks! `__future__` import was just for backwards compatibility; I tried removing it, but still the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that it should be `'environment': 'mysite.jinja2.environment',` not `'environment': 'jinja2.environment',`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure because I have defined that in `jinja2.py` in project root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you put the `jinja2.py` in a wrong position. It should be in the dir `mysite/`.

This is the directory structure of my django project `mysite`(Jin2 is a app dir), which can run normally:

```
➜ /tmp/jinja/mysite $ tree . -I '*.pyc'
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── jin2
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jinja2
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jinja2.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── __pycache__
```

My `settings.py` and `jinja2.py` are same as yours. The  only difference is that I put the `jinja2.py` in the mysite dir.

And you should delete the `from __future__ import absolute_import` in the `jinja2.py`, it is only needed in python2.

Comment: Perfect! This resolved the issue. Another thing, if you can tell, you have placed your `jinja2` directory inside an app and it may be working fine. But I need to add some project wide templates, so as you can see `base.html` in `jinja2` directory at project level, it's not working for me. The error now says `TemplateDoesNotExist`. Should this work because the documentation says if we set `APP_DIRS = True`, then no need to define `DIRS`.

Comment: I resolved this by setting `'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jinja2'), ],`. Do let me know if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Oh, sorry. If you need some project wide templates.I also only konw to set the `DIRS` options.

Answer (score 0):

You've called your own file `jinja2`. So Python finds that instead of the actual Jinja2 library when you do `import jinja2`.

Call your file something else.

Comment: I changed the name of `jinja2.py` file to `jin.py` and updated the settings file where it was called. But now I get a different error `No module named 'mysite.jin'`.

Comment: The `environment`'s import path is `mysite.jinja2.environment`.That means find the `environment` in the `mysite`'s submodule `jinjia2`. So it can be named `jinja2`.

Comment: Yes, it works with the name `jinja2.py`, just the location of the file was incorrect.